# Problems with comboboxes in a userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am working within a userform and I am coding on comboboxes. I have put a drop down list in my combobox using `.additem`, and every time a user presses on one of the items in the list, a message box should appear.

For some reason, my first code makes the message box reappear on the next row within the combobox so when the second row is pressed I have two message boxes instead of one.

Is it because of the `and` function? Is there another way to do this?

To clarify, `ComboBox1.ListIndex = 2` (2 message boxes appear whereas I need only the one which is the one I have coded) and `ComboBox1.ListIndex = 3` (3 message boxes appear instead of 1).

```
If ComboBox1.ListIndex = 1 And Msgbox("Do you want to create a new company?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then UserForm1.Show

If ComboBox1.ListIndex = 2 And Msgbox("Do you want to open the reports screen?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then UserForm2.Show

If ComboBox1.ListIndex = 3 And Msgbox("Are you sure", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then Unload AccountsVbaPro
```

Answer (score 1):

The `And` *operator* (not *function*) doesn't *short-circuit*<sup>1</sup>, so in order to evaluate whether the Boolean expression result is `True`, VBA needs the result of the `MsgBox` function... for each condition.

```
'both foo and bar need to be evaluated to know whether DoSomething needs to run:
If foo And Bar Then DoSomething
```

Make the `MsgBox` calls conditional - I'd suggest using a `Select Case` block, to avoid repeating the `ComboBox1.ListIndex` member access every time:

```
Select Case ComboBox1.ListIndex
   Case 1
       If Msgbox("Do you want to create a new company?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then UserForm1.Show
   Case 2
       If Msgbox("Do you want to open the reports screen?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then UserForm2.Show
   Case 3
       If Msgbox("Are you sure", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then Unload AccountsVbaPro
End Select
```

Note that `UserForm1.Show` / `UserForm2.Show` are [likely going to cause problems](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) eventually, as is `Unload AccountsVbaPro` if that code is in the code-behind of a form named `AccountsVbaPro`.

---

<sup>1</sup>A short-circuiting operator does not exist in VBA. In e.g. VB.NET, you get to use the `AndAlso` and `OrElse` operators, which do. The consequence of *short-circuiting* logical operators, is that evaluating a Boolean expression can bail out once its result is known:

```
If True Or True Or False Then ' all operands need to be evaluated
```

vs

```
If True OrElse True OrElse False Then ' evaluation stops at the first True; 2nd & 3rd operands are skipped
```

Comment: Wow that works Mathieu Guindon  thank you for that. I am completely new to programming so I had no idea you could use (select case). As for the  Note that UserForm1.Show / UserForm2.Show are likely to create problems when will those problems occur?

Comment: When you start `New`ing stuff up. See linked article ;-)